# Alternative for getent to launch containerized ShinyProxy with a docker engine

Tags: bash, docker

I'm following this [tutorial to launch a containerized ShinyProxy with a docker enine](https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-config-examples/tree/master/02-containerized-docker-engine). It works as expected, until there is this [`getent`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getent.1.html) command [that seems to be unavailable for MacOS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373309/mac-os-command-to-resolve-hostnames-like-getent-on-linux) :(

```bsh
sudo docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro --group-add $(getent group docker | cut -d: -f3) --net sp-example-net -p 8080:8080 shinyproxy-example
```

I tested the outcome of `getent group docker | cut -d: -f3` on a Linux computer running Debian 11 (where it was possible to open the apps within the ShinyProxy docker image, btw):

```bsh
$ getent group docker
docker:x:998:r
$ getent group docker | cut -d: -f3
998
```

I tried to achieve similar on a MacOS 12.2 with `dscacheutil`, but there seems to be no group named `docker`:

```bsh
$ dscacheutil -q group | grep docker
```

Out of desparation, I tried to launch docker without the `--group-add`-part, but then ShinyProxy dumps its cores. Thus, my question: what command can replace `getent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `id` command instead:

```
id -G docker
```

This will tell you which groups the `docker` user is a part of.

Comment: This answers how to rep[lace getent - however on macOS my DOcker Desktop has not created a docker user. A quick google gives and old issue that might be useful https://support.openanalytics.eu/t/failed-to-create-container-macos/618/4

Comment: Well, the question specifically says at the end that this question is on replacing getent … it’s not the right way to look at this from a general perspective, but that was the question.

Comment: Thank you, jksoegaard, for your quick response. However: `id -G docker
id: docker: no such user`. It seems as there is [no user group for docker on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70385997/4112892)... confusing... Anyway, I assume your answer *would* be the correct one if there *was* a user group for docker on MacOS...

Comment: You could have one if you wanted, I don't know your setup - but in a default setup, there's none. I would advise opening a new question with the core dump, and see if you can find logs or error messages before the core dump.

Comment: Thank you, jksoegaard. Yaa, I have seen that you could create a user group. But honestly, I'm unsure if it is necessary. Yesterday, I was about to open a question on [openanalytics' support page](https://support.openanalytics.eu/), but when I wanted to create the logs with the core dump, the server started to run (and I tried several times before o_O), although veeeery slowly. So, in the end I might have been on the wrong track anyway, but still learnt something in the end. I will leave a comment here, once I figured it out.

Comment: Short update: I think this behaviour is to [trace back on the Apple M1 chips](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/#known-issues). A workaround could be a Linux VM.